# spring integration 4.1.x channel vs message template send operation

Tags: spring-integration

In Spring integration app, you can send message to channel in different ways. Two of them are, you can use channel.send(msg) and MessageTemplate.convertAndSend(channel,msg).

Can anyone tell me the difference and which is recommended? What is the drwaback of others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another more high-level way to send message - `@MessagingGateway`, where your source client is fully free from Messaging API.

On the other hand it is up to use what to use on the matter.

The `MessageChannel.send()` API is very low and don't provide so much control over the message.

The `MessagingTemplate` can be configured as a bean with some common options like `MessageConverter`, which is really used by the aforementioned `convertAndSend()`. But in the end it is, of course, just `MessageChannel.send()`.

There is no any recommendations, but `MessagingTemplate` has been introduced for convenience.